# Import data from different Workbooks VBA

Tags: vba, import

I have a code see below to import data from different workbooks inside one folder. I try it and it works perfectly however I was wondering if someone could help me to improve it.

I explain:  "zmaster.xlms" workbook is the one where all data are past in sheet one. In this same workbook in sheet2 i have a table like this:

[image]

Where the column "Excel Column code" is where the data should be past (in the "zmaster.xlms") and "Form Cell Code" correspond to the cells which should be copy from every workbooks (which are in the same file in my desktop).

Question: How To say to the macro to look at the table and copy the cell K26 and past it in the columnA of the zmaster file and loop until the end of the table?

```
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = "C:\Desktop\New folder\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
'    Range("A1:D1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

    MyFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: I just update my post. sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to loop through the cells in `sheet 2` (`zmaster.xlsm`). Have a look at example code. Please, read comments.

**[EDIT]**

Code has been updated!

```
Option Explicit

'assuming that:
'- "Excel Column Code" is in column A
'- "Form Cell Code" is in column B
'in zmaster.xlsm!Sheet2


Sub UpdateData()
Dim sFile As String, sPath As String
Dim srcWbk As Workbook, dstWbk As Workbook
Dim srcWsh As Worksheet, dstWsh As Worksheet, infoWsh As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

On Error GoTo Err_UpdateData


Set dstWbk = ThisWorkbook
Set dstWsh = dstWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set infoWsh = dstWbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")

sPath = "C:\Desktop\New folder\"
sFile = Dir(sPath)
Do While Len(sFile) > 0
    If sFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
    GoTo SkipNext
    End If

    Set srcWbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)
    Set srcWsh = srcWbk.Worksheets(1)
    i = 2
    'loop through the information about copy-paste method
    Do While infoWsh.Range("A" & i) <> ""
        'get first empty row, use "Excel Column Code" to get column name
        j = GetFirstEmpty(dstWsh, infoWsh.Range("A" & i))
        'copy data from source sheet to the destination sheet
        'use "Form Cell Code" to define destination cell
        srcWsh.Range(infoWsh.Range("B" & i)).Copy dstWsh.Range(infoWsh.Range("A" & i) & j)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    srcwbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
SkipNext:
    sFile = Dir
Loop

Exit_UpdateData:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set srcWsh = Nothing
    Set dstWsh = Nothing
    Set srcWbk = Nothing
    Set dstWbk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_UpdateData:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_UpdateData
End Sub

'returns first empty row in a destination sheet based on column name
Function GetFirstEmpty(ByVal wsh As Worksheet, Optional ByVal sCol As String = "A") As Long

GetFirstEmpty = wsh.Range(sCol & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

End Function
```

Comment: Thank for your code and comments but i have an error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Oh.... the code i have providen were writen stright from the head.... Please, debug the program and tell me the line in which error ocuurs.

Comment: Seems, that this line have to be changed as follow: `srcWsh.Range(infoWsh.Range("B" & i)).Copy dstWsh.Range(infoWsh.Range("A" & i), j)`

Comment: The first workbook in the file open correctly and then there is a window with error 438.

Comment: I still have the same problem with this line

Comment: As i mentioned, please, debug the program (use F8) to find the reason of trouble.

Comment: I got it! Replace this line: `GetFirstEmpty = wsh.Range(sCol & wsh.Rows.coun).End(xlUp).Row + 1` with `GetFirstEmpty = wsh.Range(sCol & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` Use updated code.

Comment: So, please, accept my answer as a solution. You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you code

```
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
```

is simply copying columns A to D of the first row of data  in the source worksheet to a new row in the destination worksheet.

I'm assuming that you still want to create a new single row, but that you want the table on sheet2 to define which cells are put into which column of the new row.

you need to write something like this (which is untested):

```
Sub YourCode()

    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim Filepath As String

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource  As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet

    Dim rngMapping As Range

    Dim DestinationRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range


    Filepath = "C:\Desktop\New folder\"
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

    Set wsDestination = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1

     ' Named range "MappingTableFirstColumn" is defined as having the first column in the sheet2 table and all the rows of the table.
    Set rngMapping = ActiveWorkbook.Names("MappingTable").RefersToRange

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
        End If

        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

        DestinationRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        For Each cell In rngMapping

            wsDestination.Range(cell.Value & DestinationRow) = wsSource.Range(cell.Offset(0, 1)).Value

        Next cell

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank HarvyFrench! But It seems to have a problem with Me.Sheet1. It says INVALIDE USE OF ME KEYWORD